# Nav bar appears twice doesn't respect php if statement

Tags: php, html, html-lists, nav

I am trying to change my navigation bar depending on whether the user has signed in. Eventually also checking whether the user is an admin or not and having different list items depending on these conditions.

The issue is since my condition is in PHP it doesn't seem to respect the if statement and when the page is loaded both ul are shown.

I have a session start at the top of my page so the value of "loggedin" should be stored.

```
<header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="Logo">
        <img src="./images/LogoSmall.png" width="60px" height="60px" alt="Logo">
        <h2> Quality Speakers Global </h2>
    </div>
    <div>
    <nav>
    <?php
        if($_SESSION["loggedin"] == "yes"){
        ?>
        <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Register.html">Login/Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="Slideshow.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="Report.html">Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="userpage.php">My Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    <?php } else{?>
        <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Register.html">Login/Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="Slideshow.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="Report.html">Report</a></li>
        </ul>       
    <?php       
    }
    ?>

    </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

What i want is to only show the ul depending on the condition

here is my php login code:

```
<?php

  session_start();

  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','pass1','accounts');

  if(isset($_POST["UsernameLogin"])) {

      $Logusername = $_POST['UsernameLogin']; 
  }

  if(isset($_POST["PasswordLogin"])) {

      $Logpassword = $_POST['PasswordLogin'];
  }

  $query = " select * from users where username = '$Logusername' && password = '$Logpassword'";

  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($num == 1) {
      $_SESSION["username"] = $Logusername;
      $_SESSION["level"] = $row["usertype"];
      $_SESSION["loggedin"] = 'yes';

      if($_SESSION["level"] == "admin") {

          header('location:AccountsPage.php');
      } else {

          header('location:userpage.php');
      }   
  } else {
    header("Location: Index.html");

  }

?>
```

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Did you put `session_start() at the beginning of every page?

Comment: have you started the session `session_start()` on your header or menu page? on above `if($_SESSION["loggedin"] == "yes")` ?

Comment: Yes i have a session_start()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `index.html` page is not being parsed as php.  Change the extension to `.php` or change configuration to also parse html files.

Comment: Thank you very much that seems to have been the issue! very silly mistake from me!